# One-Class classifier using Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I'm having a problem setting up a proper Neural Network for one class classification. Basically I've only the features that rapresent a background of an image. So the training phase would train the NN on those features. During the execution phase the NN will have features that could be "background" or "foreground" (the upper step is segmentation, I've already done it). NOTE: I can't train NN on "foreground" because I don't know if the segmentation process acquires only foreground objects. How I'm supposed to set up correctly my NN?

Here is some piece of code:

```
toTrainFeat = computeFeatures(backBboxes,frame);
classes(1:size(backBboxes,1))=1;             % one-class
[net Y E] = adapt(net,toTrainFeat,classes);  % Incremental learning
if numFrame >=40 || sse(E) <0.01             %classify only after 40 frames OR if NN is smart enough
  y = net(toClassifyFeat);
  y
end
```

This code does not work, I think because I'm submitting only ONE-CLASS to the adapt method (in fact it crashes when it call adapt). Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "background" or "foreground"  <- 2 classes. One class classification is very easy, you don't need a NN. EVERYTHING is from that class.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure that all the blobs that I acquire are foreground, I've to classify to detect false positives. I've edited the question.

Comment: You need to train a NN with real data. You can not rain it with only half of the data. If  a NN hasen't seen a type of data, it wont know how to clasify it

Comment: @AnderBiguri maybe I'm not explaining it well. I've background data, I can acquire it. So I train NN; now I want to use this trained NN to classify blobs from segmentation process. 97% of them will be "foreground", so NN will not recognize them (very low confidence), while other 3% are background and I've to filter them. That's the idea, but I need a one class classification.

Comment: No I still not understand. What do you mean "NN" wont recognize them? A NN will do what it is trained to. If you train it to detec cats or dogs and inset a house, it will clasify it as a cat or a dog, but never as a house. If you trained it to clasify foreground and background , and data is either of the, it will do the job. If you havent trained it to clasify foreground, it will just not do it. The statistic of the data are irrelevant, 400 dogs and 1 cat will be properly classified (as long as the training was good)

Comment: @AnderBiguri with "not recognize them" I meant a very low confidence of result. Ok it will look at foreground and will recognize as background, but with a very little confidence. Am I wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125703/discussion-between-leo91-and-ander-biguri).